# search and replace with sed not working

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to use sed for search and replace, but it doesn't seem to be working.
I guess I'm making a stupid mistake I can't spot.

here is my file.txt:

```
PFPR03  PA1448770
PFPR03  PA1448780
PFPR03  PA1448790
PFPR03  PA1448800
PFPR03  PA1448810
PFPR03  PA1448830
PFPR03  PA1448840
PFPR03  PA1448850
PFPR03  PA1448860
PFPR03  PA1448870
```

I want to change PA1448770 to PA14_48770, ie. adding an underscore after the PA14.

Here are a few examples of what I've tried, none of them are affecting the file at all:

```
sed 's/^PA14/PA14_/g' file.txt
sed 's/^PA14([0-9]*)/PA14_\1/' file.txt
```

Any help is appreciated,

Comment: `^` anchors at the beginning of the line.  `PA14` is never at the beginning of the line, thus your search never finds it.

Comment: Why are you using `g`? Does it appear more than once per line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `^` means line start. Use `\b` for word boundary:

```
sed 's/\bPA14/PA14_/g' file
PFPR03  PA14_48770
PFPR03  PA14_48780
PFPR03  PA14_48790
PFPR03  PA14_48800
PFPR03  PA14_48810
PFPR03  PA14_48830
PFPR03  PA14_48840
PFPR03  PA14_48850
PFPR03  PA14_48860
PFPR03  PA14_48870
```

PS: On OSX (BSD) `sed` use:

```
sed 's/[[:<:]]PA14/PA14_/g' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using this token `^`, which means `start of string`. That's either the beginning of a line, or of an entire file, but certainly not the beginning of a word.
So this should work :

`sed 's/PA14/PA14_/g' file.txt`

**edit**

I highly recommend [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to practice your regex. You can test your expressions in live, and they have lot's of good explanations about tokens.

Comment: Or type a bit less: `s/PA14/&_/`